# How to use custom transitions from resource file

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I've just written a new custom transition but I'm not sure how to completely define it so can be used in the transition resource files for example `res/transition/rotate_transition.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="275"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"/>
```

Here is my rotate transition code below:

```
  public class Rotate extends Transition {

  private static final String PROPNAME_ROTATION = "com.example.transition:rotate:rotation";

  @Override
  public void captureStartValues(TransitionValues transitionValues) {
    captureValues(transitionValues);
  }

  @Override
  public void captureEndValues(TransitionValues transitionValues) {
    captureValues(transitionValues);
  }

  @Override
  public Animator createAnimator(
      ViewGroup sceneRoot, TransitionValues startValues, TransitionValues endValues) {

    float startValue = (float) startValues.values.get(PROPNAME_ROTATION);
    float endValue = (float) endValues.values.get(PROPNAME_ROTATION);
    View view = endValues.view;

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startValue, endValue);
    animator.addUpdateListener(
        animation -> {
          float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
          view.setRotation(value);
        });

    return animator;
  }

  private void captureValues(TransitionValues values) {
    View view = values.view;
    values.values.put(PROPNAME_ROTATION, view.getRotation());
  }
}
```

My question is what else should I initialize in order to get this work because now I am only getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown scene name: rotate`?

Comment: see `TransitionInflater.java` source file (and find `createTransitionFromXml` method)

Comment: I'm already using it in the activitiy like this:
    Transition transition =
        TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.rotate_transition);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(container, transition);

    if (view.getRotation() == 90.0f) {
      view.setRotation(0f);
    } else {
      view.setRotation(90.0f);
    }
Then I get this runtime error.

Comment: yes, i know, it throws `RuntimeException`

Comment: If I use <fade/> transition in the xml file instead of <rotate/>, everything works fine.

Comment: so did you see `TransitionInflater#createTransitionFromXml()` method source code?

Comment: Thank you I found what you were thinking. In that method are hardcoded all transitions defined by default, but I'm not sure how to solve my problem except write a new wrapper for the TransitionInflater.

Comment: you want `Transition transition`, right? so make a new `Rotate()` object: `Transition transition = new Rotate();`

Comment: I am aware of that, but I want to use it from the resource file instead. That is why I'm asking if there is a way to do that. Thanks!